# Как подменить директорию для записи/чтения фала на apache в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть сайт, в php скриптах прописаны пути для загрузки файлов из всевозможных форм
например:

> /sites/files/some_dir/

Возможно ли в файле .htaccess, подменить этот путь?  чтобы все файлы, записывающиеся в эту директорию отправлялись на другой сайт (там я уже расшарил папки для записи, если надо напишу необходимые проверки).

то есть при попытке записать файл в

> /sites/files/some_dir/

он сразу же перекидывался в

> http://sub.mysite.ru/sites/files/some_dir/

А при попытке чтения например

> /sites/files/some_dir/image.jpg

файл считывался с

> http://sub.mysite.ru/sites/files/some_dir/image.jpg

Читал, что mod_rewrite обладает широкими возможностями, для настройки всевозможных редиректов, но не нашел, информации по тому можно ли настроить подмену директорий при записи/чтении файла

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно. Правила в htaccess(nginx) имеют высший приоритет. Смотрите здесь, например, 301 редирект в файле .htaccess. Примеры http://coderhs.com/archive/redirect_301 И не обязательно через mod_rewrite. Попробуйте и напишите сюда код, если не сработает - учитываейте логику работы вашего сайта и прочее.